# Order Prefix wont work

Tags: magento-1.9, database, prefix

I changed in the table "eav_entity_text" my order "increment prefix" into "ON-" and in "increment_last_id" i set it to "ON-10001".
Also i changed in table "eav_entity_type" the "increment_pad_length" of orders to "5". 
But when i now make a order everytime my store adds a "1" to the order increment ID.

For example: 
 - First order: 10002
 - Second order: 110003
 - Third order: 1110004
and so on...

I dont know whats going wrong? It wont use my prefix for orders, for invoices it works well...

Answer (score -1):

If anybody got the same error, I have fixed it finally.
It seems like I had set the `entity_store_id` in table `eav_entity_store` for the orders entry to 0. Since I changed it back to 1 everything works well.